# external CSS, test on local computer, css file not found

Tags: html, css

I just started to implement a website. I have no host yet. First I would like to try some things locally on my own laptop.

I would like to use external css.

A simple version of the index file to show the problem looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The test.css looks like this:

```
<style>
h1 {
color: red;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that the html file does not find the css file (the header will be black instead of red) although they are located in the same directory. I tried some variants but it did not help.

If I add the same css code inline, then it works.

This should be very easy, but I fail to see why the html file does not find the external file.

I tried this on firefox and IE.

Hope somebody could help me.

Answer (score 3):

you missed open html tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

remove `style` from your css file

```
h1 {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but don't *try*, just *do*; HTML should not be anyone's .css files.

Comment: yes, that's right, thanks for the correction

Comment: Thanks, I removed the style tags from the css file. But it still does not work. (Note that both files are located in the same directory,.)

Comment: I corrected the answer, you missed the open html tag, although it closes at the end

Comment: Many thank's, now it works. So I managed to make two errors - pretty alarming - but in the end things will be alright! Thank's.